# Vagrant synced_folder /vagrant shared_folder missing

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

Hi I'm trying to provision my box using vagrant and ansible but I always encounter /vagrant/ansible/playbook.yml is missing. It's looking for a /vagrant directory. When I ssh inside my box the /vagrant does not exist. I'm not sure what happen but what I did was to sync all my local copy into a specific folder location inside my box. Below is a sample implementation I did

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "ans", primary: true do |ans|
        ans.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
        ans.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
        ans.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.8.9.20", auto_network: true
        ans.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/"
        ans.vm.hostname = "my_project"
        ans.vm.provision "pre-build", type: "shell", :path => "ansible/bootstrap.sh"
        ans.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
        end
    end
end
```

I'm getting an error in the `ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"` it seems this line is looking under /vagrant folder which does not exist. What will be the workaround or fix for this? My playbook exist in this location `/var/www/ansible/playbook.yml` inside the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, vagrant automatically add a shared folder from your current directory with `/vagrant` folder on the VM.

Because you have added

```
ans.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/"
```

the current folder shared folder has been replaced from `/vagrant` to `/var/www` (you can easily verify that by removing the line from your vagrantfile)

do you really need to sync the whole current folder with `/var/www` ideally you would have your project files in a subdirectory that you will share in `/var/www` like

```
ans.vm.synced_folder "html/", "/var/www/"
```

and push all your html/csss/js files under the html folder (feel free to rename project or something else) and you'll not need to sync all the vagrant scripts and provisioning script with your web server folder.

Comment: So it means that to make /vagrant and /var/www exist in the same box I need to move all my working directory inside a subfolder?

Comment: no .. sorry, I am probably not clear, you can have as many shared folders from host to VM but you cannot have 2 identical host folder pointing to different folder in VM. so you will have the default `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"` that shares all your current directory with vagrant and sensible provisioning script (+subdirectory) and one `config.vm.synced_folder "./project", "/var/www"` where project folder will contain only the files needed in the web server directory

Comment: I see.. I'll try changing my Vagrantfile then. I think this will fix my issue. Will accept your answer once it solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: I was able to fix it thanks to your advice. I added `ans.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"` and `ans.vm.synced_folder "../my_project", "/var/www/"` so basically I just told vagrant to go back one level back and then go search the project folder and sync it in /var/www

Comment: right .. as long as its 2 different values, this is fine